# Проблема с созданием собственной карты yandex map

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Всем привет.
Нужна помощь.
Хочу сделать собственную карту, на основе yandex map.
Изучил все api 2.1 подготовил тайлы на приложении яндекса.
В итоге карта выгружается только в одном маштабровании.
Код беру отсюда [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map)

код загрузки:

```
ymaps.ready(function () {

    var LAYER_NAME = 'user#layer',
        MAP_TYPE_NAME = 'user#customMap',
        // Директория с тайлами.
        TILES_PATH = '-/ya.maps/<?=$arResult['ID']?>',
        /* Для того чтобы вычислить координаты левого нижнего и правого верхнего углов прямоугольной координатной
         * области, нам необходимо знать максимальный зум, ширину и высоту изображения в пикселях на максимальном зуме.
         */
        MAX_ZOOM = 4,
        PIC_WIDTH = 1024,
        PIC_HEIGHT = 685;

    /**
     * Конструктор, создающий собственный слой.
     */
    var Layer = function () {
        var layer = new ymaps.Layer(TILES_PATH + '/%z/tile-%x-%y.jpg', {
        // var layer = new ymaps.Layer(TILES_PATH + '/%z/%x/%y.png', {
            // Если есть необходимость показать собственное изображение в местах неподгрузившихся тайлов,
            // раскомментируйте эту строчку и укажите ссылку на изображение.
            // notFoundTile: 'url'
        });
        // Указываем доступный диапазон масштабов для данного слоя.
        layer.getZoomRange = function () {
            return ymaps.vow.resolve([0, 4]);
        };
        // // Добавляем свои копирайты.
        // layer.getCopyrights = function () {
        //     return ymaps.vow.resolve('©');
        // };
        return layer;
    };
    // Добавляем в хранилище слоев свой конструктор.
    ymaps.layer.storage.add(LAYER_NAME, Layer);

    /**
     * Создадим новый тип карты.
     * MAP_TYPE_NAME - имя нового типа.
     * LAYER_NAME - ключ в хранилище слоев или функция конструктор.
     */
    var mapType = new ymaps.MapType(MAP_TYPE_NAME, [LAYER_NAME]);
    // Сохраняем тип в хранилище типов.
    ymaps.mapType.storage.add(MAP_TYPE_NAME, mapType);

    // Вычисляем размер всех тайлов на максимальном зуме.
    var worldSize = Math.pow(2, MAX_ZOOM) * 256,
        /**
         * Создаем карту, указав свой новый тип карты.
         */
        map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [100, 100],
            zoom: 2,
            controls: ['zoomControl'],
            type: MAP_TYPE_NAME
        }, {

            // Задаем в качестве проекции Декартову. При данном расчёте центр изображения будет лежать в координатах [0, 0].
            // projection: new ymaps.projection.Cartesian([[PIC_HEIGHT / 2 - worldSize, -PIC_WIDTH / 2], [PIC_HEIGHT / 2, worldSize - PIC_WIDTH / 2]], [false, false]),
            // Устанавливаем область просмотра карты так, чтобы пользователь не смог выйти за пределы изображения.
            // restrictMapArea: [[-PIC_HEIGHT / 2, -PIC_WIDTH / 2], [PIC_HEIGHT / 2, PIC_WIDTH / 2]]

            // При данном расчёте, в координатах [0, 0] будет находиться левый нижний угол изображения,
            // правый верхний будет находиться в координатах [PIC_HEIGHT, PIC_WIDTH].
            projection: new ymaps.projection.Cartesian([[PIC_HEIGHT - worldSize, 0], [PIC_HEIGHT, worldSize]], [false, false]),
            restrictMapArea: [[0, 0], [PIC_HEIGHT, PIC_WIDTH]]
        });
    console.log(worldSize);
    // Ставим метку в центр координат. Обратите внимание, координаты метки задаются в порядке [y, x].
    var point = new ymaps.Placemark([635, 800], {
        balloonContent: 'jfklsdjfklsj'
    }, {
        preset: 'islands#darkOrangeDotIcon'
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(point);
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
неработает маштабирование.
и непонятно как это все исправить.
Перепробовал почти все параметры.
структура тайлов 0-4 папки, в 4-ой папке последний тайл 3-2.

Comment: Добрый день, добавьте ссылку на страницу с проблемой или соберите пример на jsfiddle, без примера тяжело увидеть в чем проблема.

Comment: Вот собрал в fiddle [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/zkneon/cba20uwx/) Спасибо что откликнулся.

Comment: У вас очень маленькая картинка, если убрать ограничения https://jsfiddle.net/fed9n0jf/ то это видно. А чего добиться хотите?

Comment: Очень странно, уже крутил вертел эту программу для таилов от яндекса. Вроде бы все правильно нарезаю. Буду пробовать еще.

Comment: Какого размера картинка которую нарезаете?

Comment: Логика в том, что для 0-4 нужна очень большая картинка. Стандартный тайл это 256х256 px и это будет нулевой зум. Чтобы получить два уровня зума [0-1] нужна картинка 512x512, три уровня зума [0-2] - 1024x1024, 4 уровня [0-3] - 2048x2048.

Comment: Я режу 1024Х600, вроде логика понятна буду пробовать.